# A basic theorem of prime numbers. Checking My Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

- Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that $n^5 -1$ is prime if and only if $n=2$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Assume $n^5-1$ is prime. We will show $n=2$. If $n=3$, then clear $n^5-1$ is not prime.

Claim. If $n>2$, then $n^5-1$ is not prime.

Proof of the claim. We will do induction on $n$.

Initial Step. If $n=3$, clearly $n^5-1$ is not prime.

Induction Step. Assume for $n=m\in\mathbb{N}^{>2}$, $m^5-1$ is not prime. We will show $n=m+1\in\mathbb{N}^{>2}$, $(m+1)^5-1$ is not prime. So 
    $(m+1)^5-1=m((m+1)^4 +(m+1)^3 +(m+1)^2 +(m+1)+1)$

Let $u=m$ and $v=(m+1)^4 +(m+1)^3 +(m+1)^2 +(m+1)+1)$. Then since $m>2$, then $u>2$ and $v>2$. Thus, $uv$ cannot be a prime because $uv$ has no positive integer divisors other than $1$ and $uv$.

Therefore the claim is proved.

So by the claim, $n$ must be $2$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Assume $n=2$. Then, $n^5 -1=2^5 -1=31$ is prime.

**May you check my proof?** Thanks...

Comment: why don' t use the decomposition $n^5-1 = (n-1) (n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1)$,?

Comment: @ALG I tried. I couldn't use because in RHS, there is $(n-1)$. Maybe, I could do it.

Comment: @ALG I would say that $(m+1)^5-1=m((m+1)^4 +(m+1)^3 +(m+1)^2 +(m+1)+1)$ is that decomposition.

Comment: mfl,  So $(m+1)^5 -1 = m....$ is that decomposition but why obfuscate it?  it's not clear nor easy to read.  But $n^5 -1 = (n-1)(n^4 + n^3 + n^2 + n+1)$ is very clear and that can only be prime if if $n-1 = 1$ or $n^4 + n^3 + n^2 + 1 = 1$.  And as $n$ is a positive integer that can only occur if $n=2$.  So $n^5-1$ can only be prime if $n=2$ and if $n=2$ then $n^5 -1$ *is* prime.  .. and that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine but really long and complicated and hard to read.

Simpler to just say:

$n^5 -1 = (n-1)(n^4 + n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)$.

If $n-1$ and $n^4 + n^3 + n^2 + n + 1$ are non trivial factors (not equal to $1$ or $n^5 -1$) then this is not prime.

So the only way for $n^5 -1$ to be prime is if either $n-1 = 1$ or $n^4 + n^3 + n^2 + n +1 = 1$.

If $n -1 = 1$ then $n =2$ and if $n^4 + n^3 + n^2 + n + 1= 1$ then $n(n^3 + n^2 + n + 1) = 0$ which has no natural number solutions.

So $n^5 -1$ is not prime if $n \ne 2$.

And if $n = 2$ then $n^5 -1 = 2^5 - 1 = 31$ which is prime.

Comment: Thanks for answer.